# UK Standard Visa - Bank Statements

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I will be traveling with my wife to UK in May 2020. I had a query pertaining to my bank statement. I have a full time job and the statement clearly  shows deposits of my salary every month . However, there are deposits to my account for my wife’s part time jobs as well. Will these deposits be an issue or a probable cause of rejection?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Provide the supporting evidence for your wife’s income into your account, for example payslips, and there will be no problem.

[Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)